# C++ and Swift Don't Like Each Other

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift, c-preprocessor, constants

I am trying to use a C++ library named MP4v2 in Swift. It is mostly working in that I can can call some functions, use some classes, etc.

I am having trouble with a particular function that returns a void pointer. It is `NULL` on failure, or some other value on success. There is a constant defined to check with, but neither that nor checking for nil works.

```swift
if file != MP4_INVALID_FILE_HANDLE {
```

throws `/<path_to_project>/main.swift:19:12: Use of unresolved identifier 'MP4_INVALID_FILE_HANDLE'`, but it is DOES exist (other constants work).

`if file != NULL` just causes the same problem, and `if file != nil` never is true, even if the function failed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe if you mention which library it is, someone will know.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I added the library name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at MP4v2 documentation, here is the definition of the macro to check for invalid handle:

```
 #define    MP4_INVALID_FILE_HANDLE   ((MP4FileHandle)NULL)
```

The reason it cannot be used in Swift is because it involves a `NULL`.  In fact, if you define something like

```
#define MY_NULL NULL
```

in your Objective-C(++) code and try to use it in Swift, Swift will suggest that you use `nil` instead.

The handle type `MP4FileHandle` is

```
typedef void *  MP4FileHandle
```

So, if you are calling a function like

```
MP4FileHandle aCPPFunction()
```

You should be able to check the return value as follows in Swift:

```
let h : MP4FileHandle = aCPPFunction()

if h != nil
{
   // The handle is valid and can be given as an argument to
   // other library functions.
}
else
{
   // The handle is NULL
}
```

I understand you tried this.  It should work, please double-check.  If for whatever strange reason this doesn't work for you, there are some other options:

1. Write a simple helper function in C, C++, Objective-C or
   Objective-C++ to check if the handle is valid and return a integer
   flag, which should be easily understood by Swift.
2. Check `h.hashValue`.  If it is 0, then the handle is invalid,
   otherwise it is valid.  This is a bad undocumented hack, but it has
   worked for me.  I would stay away from this one.